# Are there ereader tablets that allow handwritten notes in ebooks?

Tags: annotations, writing

I'm looking for a tablet that one can write handwritten notes in ebooks with. I want to be able to take handwritten notes separately also, outside of ebooks, so I prefer a tablet that does more than being an ereader. I had asked about apps that allow this before, but got not responses, so I'm wondering if the functionality may be with the tablet itself, rather than the app.

Comment: The reMarkable2 tablet does that. It's a bit pricey, but I bought mine about 4(?) years ago when it came out, and I've been using it every day since. So definitely value for money.